# Sobel Edge Detection, image convolution

Tags: java, convolution, edge-detection, sobel

I am working on an assignment using sobel edge detection on an image. I am currently struggling to do the operation for the gradient. I am receiving a "bad operand types for binary operator '*'" error when compiling. I think it may be because I defined all of my pixels as letters and I'm not sure what my next step should be. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

```
public static BufferedImage sobelEdgeDetect(BufferedImage input) {
     int img_width = input.getWidth();
    int img_height = input.getHeight();

    BufferedImage output_img = new BufferedImage(
        img_width, img_height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    for (int x = 0; x < img_width; x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < img_height; y++) {

    Color color_at_pos = new Color(input.getRGB(x, y));

    int red = color_at_pos.getRed();
    int green = color_at_pos.getGreen();
    int blue = color_at_pos.getBlue();

    int average = (red + green + blue) / 3;

    Color A,B,C,D,F,G,H,I;

    if(x-1 > 0 && y+1 < img_height){
          A = new Color (input.getRGB(x-1,y+1));
        } else {
          A = Color.BLACK;
        }

        if(y+1 < img_height){
          B = new Color (input.getRGB(x,y+1));
        } else {
          B = Color.BLACK;
        }

        if(x+1 < img_width && y+1 < img_height){
          C = new Color (input.getRGB(x+1,y+1));
        } else {
          C = Color.BLACK;
        }

        if(x-1 > 0){
          D = new Color (input.getRGB(x-1,y));
        } else {
          D = Color.BLACK;
        }

        if(x+1 < img_width){
          F = new Color (input.getRGB(x+1,y));
        } else {
          F = Color.BLACK;
        }

        if(x-1 > 0 && y-1 > 0){
          G = new Color (input.getRGB(x-1,y-1));
        } else {
          G = Color.BLACK;
        }

        if(y-1 > 0){
          H = new Color (input.getRGB(x,y-1));
        } else {
          H = Color.BLACK;
        }

        if(x+1 > img_width && y-1 > 0){
          I = new Color (input.getRGB(x+1,y-1));
        } else {
          I = Color.BLACK;
        }

       int gx = (-A + (-2*D) + -G + C + (2*F)+ I);
       int gy = (A + (2*B) + C + (-G) + (-2*H) + (-I));

      int result = (int)math.sqrt((gx*gx) + (gy*gy));

        if (average < 0) {
          average = 0;
        } else if (average > 255) {
          average = 255;
        }

        Color average_color = new Color(average, average, average);

        output_img.setRGB(x, y, average_color.getRGB());
      }
    } 
     return output_img;
  }
```

Comment: these operations are not valid: `int gx = (-A + (-2*D) + -G + C + (2*F)+ I);` and nextline `int gy = (A + (2*B) + C + (-G) + (-2*H) + (-I));` also won't compile

Comment: sorry if this is obvious, but how would I make them valid?

Comment: you have to handle each color seperate `int green = Color.getGreen()`, `int red = Color.getRed()` and `int blue = Color.getBlue()` will give you `int` values which can be **added, subtracted and all the stuff you want to do** to get your gradient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem lies within the handling of Colors, here:

```
int gx = (-A + (-2*D) + -G + C + (2*F)+ I);
int gy = (A + (2*B) + C + (-G) + (-2*H) + (-I));
```

this won't work.

to get the gradient you have to either

- handle each color separate
- handle the image in grayscale

i can't tell you which one would work for you.

### handle each color separate:

using this approach you handle each color separate to detect edges for that color

```
//red:
int redGx = (-A.getRed() + (-2*D.getRed()) + -G.getRed() + C.getRed() + (2*F.getRed())+ I.getRed());
int redGy = ...

//green:
int greenGx = (-A.getGreen()...
```

### handle as gray

```
int redGx = (toGray(A) + (-2*toGray(D)) + -toGray(G) + toGray(C) + (2*toGray(F))+ toGray(I));
int redGy = ...
```

you have to provide the methode `toGray` / average the colors

```
static int toGray(Color col){
    return (color.getGreen()+color.getRed()+col.getBlue()) / 3;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I handled each color separately!

Comment: the image i'm getting back seems to only be changing to grayscale and not emphasizing highlights, though.

Comment: its gray because you do `Color average_color = new Color(average, average, average);`  to create a gray scale color of your gradient